# Getting file time in a batch file (windows)

Tags: windows, file, batch-file, command-prompt

I'm looking for a way to retrieve the file time-- down to the SECOND-- in a batch file.  I'm trying to do an operation on all files that have been modified more recently than another file.

I've used this method:

```
for %%a in (keyfile.dat) do set LAST_PUBLISHED_DATE=%%~ta
rem for %%x in (%LAST_PUBLISHED_DATE:/= %) do echo %%x
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims= " %%a in ("%LAST_PUBLISHED_DATE%") do (
    set DATE=%%a
    set TIME=%%b
    )

for /f "tokens=1,2,3 delims=/" %%a in ("%DATE%") do (
    set MON=000%%a
    set DAY=000%%b
    set YEAR=%%c
    set MON=!MON:~-2,2!
    set DAY=!DAY:~-2,2!
    set YEAR=!YEAR:~-2,2!
    )

for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=:" %%a in ("%TIME%") do (
    set HOUR=000%%a
    set MIN=000%%b
    set HOUR=!HOUR:~-2,2!
    set MIN=!MIN:~-2,2!
    )
set INT_LASTPUBLISHEDDATE=%YEAR%%MON%%DAY%%HOUR%%MIN%
```

And I've been using that to turn the last modified date into an int which I can compare against other files.  Works great.  Except sometimes I might need to run this batch more often than once a minute.

Is there some extended way that I can also get "seconds" from the file modified time?  The method above returns it in yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm format.

(Most ideal situation would be to just get the unix time of the last modification... haven't been able to locate any way to do that though!)

Thanks!

Comment: The `DELIMS` option allows you to specify more than one delimiter.  You are not bound to just one.

Comment: Regardless of that you could substring the file time just like you are doing with the DATE and TIME.

Comment: In my opinion, based upon your limited information, your entire methodology seems a little over complex. The simplest way would be to perform a directory listing, using `Dir` with its `/A` option as `-D`, to ignore directories. Then order those, using the `/O` option and sort them by date/time using `-D`, for newest first. Wrap all of that as the command within a `For /F` loop, and output each result until the file returned matches your known target file. As soon as it matches, break out of the [tag:for-loop], using a `GoTo` command.

Answer (score 0):

you can leverage vbs for this purpose.

```bat
@Echo Off & Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

(For /F "Delims=" %%G in ('TYPE "%~F0" ^| Findstr /BLIC::::') Do (Set "Line=%%G"&Echo/!Line:~3!))>"filetimes.vbs"
For /F "Delims=" %%G in ('cscript //nologo filetimes.vbs %~nx0')Do Set "%%G"
Set %~F0[
Exit /B

:::Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
:::if WScript.Arguments.Count = 0  Then
:::   WScript.Quit
:::End If

:::strfileFolder = objFSO.GetAbsolutePathName(WScript.Arguments(0)) 

:::'this line only works with cscript
:::Set v = objFSO.GetFile(WScript.Arguments(0))
:::dm=v.DateLastModified
:::dc=v.DateCreated
:::da=v.DateLastAccessed
:::WScript.StdOut.WriteLine(strfileFolder&"[Created]="&dc)
:::WScript.StdOut.WriteLine(strfileFolder&"[Modified]="&dm)
:::WScript.StdOut.WriteLine(strfileFolder&"[Accessed]="&da)
```